# Adding a function in this timed input

Tags: python

```
    from threading import Timer

    timeout = 100 / level
    t = Timer(timeout, print, ["Times Up!"])
    t.start()
    prompt = "You have %d seconds to choose the correct answer...\n" % timeout
    answer = input(prompt)
    t.cancel()
```

In this block above, I am trying to incorporate when the user runs out of time it does a function ( main_menu() ) I have tried putting it in  `t = Timer(timeout, print, ["Times Up!"], main_menu())` but it immediately does that function without waiting for the time to run out.

Comment: `t = Timer(timeout, print, ["Times Up!"], main_menu())` didn't work because you are calling it when passing it as a variable to the `Timer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about printing `"Times up!"` inside `main_menu`?

```py
from threading import Timer

def main_menu():
    print("Times Up!")
    # rest of your main_menu code here...

timeout = 100 / level
t = Timer(timeout, main_menu)
t.start()
prompt = "You have %d seconds to choose the correct answer...\n" % timeout
answer = input(prompt)
t.cancel()
```